Title: Firebase Auth Error: Missing Client Identifier [auth/missing-client-identifier] Despite Correct SHA1/SHA256 Configuration
I am encountering an error while trying to send an OTP using Firebase Authentication in my React Native app. The error message I receive is:
vbnet
Copy code
ERROR  Error sending OTP: [Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.]
I have already ensured that my SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints are correctly configured in the Firebase console, and the Play Integrity API is enabled. Despite these configurations, the error persists. Here are the steps I have taken so far:
Added SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints to the Firebase console under my project settings.
Enabled the Play Integrity API in the Google Cloud Console.
Ensured my google-services.json file is up to date and placed in the correct location in my project.
What could be causing the [auth/missing-client-identifier] error despite having the correct SHA1/SHA256 fingerprints and Play Integrity API enabled?
Are there any additional steps or configurations that I might be missing?
Is there a way to further debug this issue to get more detailed information about the root cause?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please follow the instructions of this video and add SHA1 fingerprints to your firebase project https://youtu.be/VjdOuHMPeAo?si=6RZWJ6P2bT2AYoCf

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
